# Is there a standard notation/ name for a vector which has no repeated elements?

Tags: notation, vectors

I would like to ask the following:

Suppose we want to mention that a vector $\mathbf{x}$ has no repeated elements. Is there any way to state this using some standard notation/ name, or do we have to say "no two elements of $\mathbf{x}$ are equal''(Or something like this)?

Comment: I'd say $x_i \neq x_j$ for all $x_i,x_j \in \mathbf{x}$. It's a slight abuse of notation since $\mathbf{x}$ is not a set but it conveys the meaning nicely.

Comment: @CyclotomicField what if you want to write a paper? Would you abuse the notation? Is there anything else?

Comment: simply write "$\mathbf{x}$ with $x_i\neq x_j$ for $i\neq j$"

Comment: "no two entries/coordinates of $\mathbf{x}$ are equal" is fine (I wouldn't use the word "element" here though), you could also say that "$\mathbf{x}$ is an injective tuple".